# Connecting Frontend React and Backend Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, netlify

I have a react.js frontend app deployed on netlify and a node.js backend deployed on AWS elastic beanstalk. How do I establish a connection between my frontend and backend. It is showing that i need to establish API endpoints.How to establish API endpoints and also where to establish endpoints i.e. whether to establish them in my react frontend or Node Backend?

I have tried using netlify serverless functions and AWS Lambda but couldn't figure it out. I also tried manually establishing endpoints but couldn't figure it out. How to achieve connection between the react Frontend deployed on Netlify and Node.js Backend deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?